# Defining macros based on if else in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
#define IS_PRODUCTION YES
/*****************************************************************************/

#if (IS_PRODUCTION)  /* IS PRODUCTION */

#define MAIN_SERVER_URL      @"http://www.xxxx.org/xxxx_live"
#else

#define MAIN_SERVER_URL      @"http://www.xxxx.org/xxxx_test"

#endif
```

it doesn't seem to find IS_PRODUCTION as true. What is wrong in syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros are not objective-C. There is no `YES` in the preprocessor, it is just an unknown literal (well, technically `YES` can be a macro, but it cannot be used in preprocessor conditions).

Some ways to fix that:

```
#define IS_PRODUCTION

#ifdef IS_PRODUCTION
#if defined(IS_PRODUCTION)
```

or

```
#define IS_PRODUCTION 1

#if IS_PRODUCTION
```

or

```
#define YES 1
#define IS_PRODUCTION YES

#if IS_PRODUCTION
```

but I recommend not to redefine `YES`. That's really not a good idea.

Comment: `#if` is much better than `#ifdef`.  Using `#ifdef` will yield unexpected results when someone comes along and does `#define IS_PRODUCTION 0`.